# Sphinx Search new.sph is not readable. Skipping

Tags: indexing, sphinx

On every request in my searchd.log appears following warnings:

```
[Tue Dec  9 17:05:12.468 2014] [ 5493] DEBUG: CheckRotate invoked
[Tue Dec  9 17:05:12.469 2014] [ 5493] DEBUG: conn 127.0.0.1:60103(1378659): got handshake, major v.1, err 0
[Tue Dec  9 17:05:12.469 2014] [ 5493] DEBUG: /sphinx/lib/index_1.new.sph is not readable. Skipping
[Tue Dec  9 17:05:12.469 2014] [ 5493] DEBUG: /sphinx/lib/index_1_delta.new.sph is not readable. Skipping
[Tue Dec  9 17:05:12.469 2014] [ 5493] DEBUG: /sphinx/lib/index_2.new.sph is not readable. Skipping
[Tue Dec  9 17:05:12.469 2014] [ 5493] DEBUG: /sphinx/lib/index_2_delta.new.sph is not readable. Skipping
[Tue Dec  9 17:05:12.469 2014] [ 5493] WARNING: nothing to rotate after SIGHUP ( in queue=0 )
```

I have tried to merge index'es:

```
/opt/sphinx-2.2.6/bin/indexer --config sphinx.conf --rotate index_1_delta
/opt/sphinx-2.2.6/bin/indexer --config sphinx.conf --rotate --merge index_1 index_1_delta
```

Or even rotate all:

```
/opt/sphinx-2.2.6/bin/indexer --config sphinx.conf --rotate --all
```

But it doesn't help. Any ideas how to solve this warning?

Answer (score 0):

At a guess what ever user is running 'indexer' is creating files that the user that is running 'searchd' is unable to see due to file/folder permissions.

Check your permissions.

... although the better recommendation, is to make sure you run indexer and searchd as the same user. (you would want to `chown` the files to the same user too)

Comment: It's strange but whole directory and all files are chown'ed with same user, group by which cron runs these commands. Permissions are on some files -rw-------, -rw-r--r--. Search also are running on same user. These errors occurs even there's no indexer process, it's weird.